# Can ContentChildren select vanilla html components?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component with a plain `<ng-content>` selector in the template.

I am trying to get an ElementRef instance to all html `<input />` elements that get passed as content children.

How would I write my `ContentChildren` annotation to get all the inputs.

I have tried:

```
@ContentChildren('input', { descendants: true }) _inputChildren: QueryList<any>;
```

To no avail. I would like to avoid making a directive specifically for selecting these children inputs but I will if that is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NgZone along with the query selector, although I'm not sure it's a good practice :

```js
inputs: any[];
constructor(private zone: ngZone) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    // spread operator to have an actual array and not an HTML collection
    this.inputs = [...document.querySelector('input')];
  });
}
```